# Strange array behaviour in Java

Tags: java, arrays, repaint

I'm been doing some Java coding lately and encountered this very strange problem. I wrote a class in Java that extends JPanel and resizes objects withing itself depending on its size.

For better understanding I reduced the problem to the smallest possible code.

The thing is, when I run the code following below, it would always not only set `array1[0]` but also set `array2[0]`. I don't understand why `array2` changes, even though I never made it change...

I added a little to highlight what operation I think the code does, that I can't see.

When I run the code and resize the the window, the value printed out will rapidly change and be infinity just after a little movement.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Beispiel extends JPanel {

    double[] array1, array2;

    public Beispiel(double[] array){
        array1 = array;
        array2 = array;
    }

    public void repaint(){
        try {
            array1[0] = array2[0]*this.getWidth();
            System.out.println(array2[0]);
            // array2[0] = array1[0]   <--- what i think it does
        } catch(Exception e){
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300,200);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        double[] array = {1.0,3.0};

        frame.add(new Beispiel(array));

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between an object and a reference?

Comment: I've removed "solved" from the title.  The fact that you've accepted an answer is more than sufficient to note that your issue is taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this,

```
public Beispiel(double[] array){
    array1 = array;
    array2 = array;
}
```

Try doing this and share the results

```
public Beispiel(double[] array){
    array1 = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    array2 = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
}
```

Comment: oh my god this works just fine !! thank you so much, i just tried it on my main code and it seems to function perfectly. i tried to upvote, but unfortunatly it seems i need 'reputation' points for that which i dont have since this is my first question here, sorry ._.  so do my variables array1 and array2 reach wayyy back to the argument 'array' ,which they both share, and that is why they change simultaneously? big thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Yea, I can't point you to official documentation or anything, but this is straight from personal experience. I had to deal with this when I was doing opengl model rendering, and it would change the model's points each time it iterated. Ended up doing this and it worked fine :) Set it as the answer so others can find it useful.

Comment: just did it, im still exploring the controls here xD and thanks again :D

Answer (score 2):

`array2` does change. When you use `array1 = array` and `array2 = array`, you're making `array1` and `array2` refer to the same array. So any change made to `array1` will be reflected in `array2` as well.

To solve this problem, use `java.util.Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length)` or `array.clone()` (note that this returns a shallow copy of the array, however).

Comment: is array.clone doing shallow copying?

Comment: According to the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) it does.

Comment: I have already upvote you but it is better you can indicate that in your post if you do not mind

Comment: thank you very much, @Tyler Osborne just posted the same solution, appearently i didnt have the right feeling on how variables are handed on, i think i figured it out now thank you all!

Comment: @frozn but TNT explained that in the best way.

Comment: Implement `cloneable` interface for `.clone()`